# Set Text to Search Result with Linear Search and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following search algorithm

```
        public int Search () {

        int index = -1; 

        for (int i = 0; i < bilar.size(); i++) {
            if (bilar.get(i).getMarke().equals(bilar.get(i).getMarke())) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index; 
    }
```

That search for the next Marke in my ArrayList. Mare is an variable from an class, and also contains the variable "RegNr".

Now, what I want to do is to allow an user to search for a specific Marke when an user press a button, and then prints in an text field **"The first car with the Marke (user input) is (RegNr)."**

If no such Marke exists the line **"No car with that Marke exists"** should be printed instead. How can that be achieved? 
Please let me know if something's need to be more clear.

```
private void btnSökActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String temp = txfSearch.getText();

    Search(); 
    //Something goes here
```

Comment: what is this returning for a type: ***bilar.get(i).getMarke()*** ???

Comment: Note that `bilar.get(i).getMarke().equals(bilar.get(i).getMarke())` will (hopefully) always be `true` .

Comment: This loop always breaks at first iteration

Comment: @Berger not really, it looks like OP has a custom class ans has not a properly equals implementation

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ : It seems to me that `bilar.get(i)` is something like an instance of a car, and there is very few chances that its "marke" changes between calls, it is probably the same instance of `Marke`.

Comment: You forgot an important link: https://shopcdn.textalk.se/shop/11328/art28/h6765/4346765-origpic-c2ee21.jpg

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? How to store the result returned from Search in a variable? How to check whether a result was indeed found? How to do different things based on the result of that check (i.e. how if-else works)? How to do the lookup-by-index you already did elsewhere? How to set the text of a text field? Focus on the specific issue you're having, a general "how do I do this" won't be useful to anyone else and probably won't give you a good answer, since there are too many things for each to be explained in detail.

Comment: I'm struggling how to print the result of a search algorithm in a text field

Answer (score -1):

I assume this is what you want

```
String temp = txfSearch.getText();
int found = search(temp); 
if (found > -1) {

} else {

}
```

You need to actually search for a value, not compare the list to itself

```
public int search (String find) {

    int index = -1; 

    for (int i = 0; i < bilar.size(); i++) {
        if (bilar.get(i).getMarke().equals(find)) {
            index = i;
            break;
```

Comment: Yeah but how to I set the text area to display the result?